# How to disable cache locking for testing purposes

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a Django app that uses Redis for caching. It relies on cache locking (`cache.lock()`) to reliably access and modify cache values from asynchronous tasks.

My goal, though, is to disable locking (making `cache.lock()` uneffective) on testing environments, as the asynchronous tasks become synchronous while testing and this is leading the tests to deadlocks. However, even using Django's `DummyCache`, the locking behavior seems to remain.

Am I able to disable the locking behavior in Django's cache settings? Couldn't find anything related in the docs.

**EDIT - ACTUAL QUESTION**

Sorry, I was actually replacing my Redis cache for `DummyCache` the wrong way, thus it was having no effect. My problem now, though, is that I need to fake a `lock` method for `DummyCache`, since it otherwise raises `AttributeError: 'DummyCache' object has no attribute 'lock'` in all my tests.

I'm aware that I can achieve this by mocking this method, but I would have to do this on every test class in the project. Is there maybe a cleaner way of doing this?